# JQuery - Show/hide css class, what selector to use

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The objective is to show the star beside elements in the error array:

http://jsfiddle.net/ygFYh/5/

Obviously using nth-child is not the appropriate selector.

Comment: Please provide a SIMPLIFIED example of your problem and post your code directly in the question (in addition to a jsFiddle, when possible).

Comment: I would really consider using a validation plugin such as http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ - it's not difficult to implement and is much more flexible than your homemade system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:eq` instead of `:nth-child`

but use (x-1) since they are 0-based..

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ygFYh/7/